# I'm trying to find the closest value in a reference data frame but it is not outputting the correct row. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the closest value in a reference data frame but it is not outputting the correct row.

I am using the below data frame which is then used to find the relevant row corresponding to the closest value in column 'P' to a defined variable. For example if p = 0.22222 then the code should output row 2.

DF:

```
      P   n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      n7      n8      n9   
0   NaN  0.0  0.2000  0.4000  0.6000  0.8000  1.0000  1.2000  1.4000  1.6000
1   0.0  1.0  0.8039  0.6286  0.4855  0.3753  0.2929  0.2318  0.1863  0.1520   
2   0.2  1.0  0.7983  0.6201  0.4771  0.3683  0.2876  0.2279  0.1835  0.1500   
3   0.4  1.0  0.7789  0.5924  0.4508  0.3473  0.2720  0.2167  0.1754  0.1442   
4   0.6  1.0  0.7349  0.5377  0.4043  0.3124  0.2470  0.1989  0.1628  0.1351   
5   0.8  1.0  0.6301  0.4433  0.3368  0.2658  0.2147  0.1762  0.1465  0.1234   
6   1.0  0.5  0.3828  0.3105  0.2559  0.2130  0.1787  0.1510  0.1286  0.1102   
7   1.2  0.0  0.1544  0.1871  0.1795  0.1621  0.1433  0.1257  0.1103  0.0965   
8   1.4  0.0  0.0717  0.1101  0.1216  0.1197  0.1120  0.1024  0.0925  0.0831   
9   1.6  0.0  0.0400  0.0682  0.0829  0.0876  0.0865  0.0824  0.0765  0.0707   
10  1.8  0.0  0.0249  0.0449  0.0580  0.0647  0.0668  0.0659  0.0633  0.0597   
11  2.0  0.0  0.0168  0.0312  0.0418  0.0485  0.0519  0.0528  0.0520  0.0502   
12  3.0  0.0  0.0042  0.0082  0.0118  0.0149  0.0174  0.0193  0.0207  0.0216
```

The function I am using however outputs the incorrect value:

```
p = 0.2020202
closest_p = df.iloc[(df['P']-p).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

Expected output:

```
      P   n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      n7      n8      n9   
2   0.2  1.0  0.7983  0.6201  0.4771  0.3683  0.2876  0.2279  0.1835  0.1500
```

However it is only outputting the last row -

```
      P   n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      n7      n8      n9   
12  3.0  0.0  0.0042  0.0082  0.0118  0.0149  0.0174  0.0193  0.0207  0.0216
```

Where am i going wrong????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
closest_p = (df['P']-p).abs().idxmin()
```

Output: `2`

For the row: `df.loc[(df['P']-p).abs().idxmin()]`

A fix of your approach would have been to use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) (but it's less efficient):

```
closest_p = df.loc[(df['P']-p).abs().sort_values().index[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a tie on index 0 and index 2.  Use a dictionary to find the min values

```
data="""
Index  P   n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      n7      n8      n9   
0   NaN  0.0  0.2000  0.4000  0.6000  0.8000  1.0000  1.2000  1.4000  1.6000
1   0.0  1.0  0.8039  0.6286  0.4855  0.3753  0.2929  0.2318  0.1863  0.1520   
2   0.2  1.0  0.7983  0.6201  0.4771  0.3683  0.2876  0.2279  0.1835  0.1500   
3   0.4  1.0  0.7789  0.5924  0.4508  0.3473  0.2720  0.2167  0.1754  0.1442   
4   0.6  1.0  0.7349  0.5377  0.4043  0.3124  0.2470  0.1989  0.1628  0.1351   
5   0.8  1.0  0.6301  0.4433  0.3368  0.2658  0.2147  0.1762  0.1465  0.1234   
6   1.0  0.5  0.3828  0.3105  0.2559  0.2130  0.1787  0.1510  0.1286  0.1102   
7   1.2  0.0  0.1544  0.1871  0.1795  0.1621  0.1433  0.1257  0.1103  0.0965   
8   1.4  0.0  0.0717  0.1101  0.1216  0.1197  0.1120  0.1024  0.0925  0.0831   
9   1.6  0.0  0.0400  0.0682  0.0829  0.0876  0.0865  0.0824  0.0765  0.0707   
10  1.8  0.0  0.0249  0.0449  0.0580  0.0647  0.0668  0.0659  0.0633  0.0597   
11  2.0  0.0  0.0168  0.0312  0.0418  0.0485  0.0519  0.0528  0.0520  0.0502   
12  3.0  0.0  0.0042  0.0082  0.0118  0.0149  0.0174  0.0193  0.0207  0.0216
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
for column in df.columns:
    df[column]=df[column].astype(float)
df=df.set_index('Index')
columns=df.columns

#print(df)
p = 0.2020202
n=len(df)

objdict={}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    deviations=[]
    for column in columns:
        x=row[column]
        deviation=(abs(x-p)) 
        #print(deviation)
        if deviation >=0:
            deviations.append(deviation)
    variance=min(deviations)
    objdict[index]=variance
    
print(objdict)

temp = min(objdict.values())
print(temp)

result = {key:val for key,val in objdict.items() if val == min(objdict.values())}

print(result)
```

output:

```
{0.0: 0.0020201999999999998, 2.0: 0.0020201999999999998}
```